# nginx block if it contains breaks

Tags: nginx

Looking to block any requests that contain the following strings in nginx

```
'%0d','%0a','%0D','%0A'
```

Just really looking to return like a 500 error or such.. Nothing fancy

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think a server-level if is what you need.  If you want to search the whole request, including args, you should be able to use:

```
server {
  if ($request_uri ~ %0[adAD]) { return 500; }
}
```

If you just want to check the path part of the uri:

```
server {
  if ($uri ~ [\r\n]) { return 500; }
}
```

should do the job